# From a vector of integers, build a longer vector including all integers whose distance from the original ones is at most 10

Tags: r, vector, seq

I have this integer vector:

```
m <- 10
n <- 1000
index <- sample(seq_len(n), m)
```

I want to extend `index`, by including all integers whose distance from one of the values in `index` is no greater than 10, and eliminate duplicates. Duplicates are not very likely, with the current values of `n` and `m`, but better safe than sorry, and **anyway the solution must work with generic values of `n` and `m`, with `m<n`**.

Right now I do the following:

```
library(purrr)
index <- unique(sort(unlist(map(index, function(x) seq(x - 10, x + 10)))))
```

This works, but it's not exactly very readable. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can pipe it to make this readable

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map(index, ~ seq(.x - 10, .x + 10) ) %>% # get the sequence 
         unlist %>%    # unlist the list to a vector
         unique %>%    # get the unique values
         sort          # sort
```

---

Instead of looping, we can also vectorize this by `rep`licating the index and then add the sequence of number from -10:10, get the `unique` elements and `sort`

```
out2 <- sort(unique(rep(index, each = 21) + (-10:10)))
identical(out, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow! Can you explain why the last one works? Is it some kind of broadcasting?

Comment: @DeltaIV  It works because you are basically doing the replication.  For e.g. `v1 <- 1:3;  v2 <- -10:10; rep(v1, each = length(v2)) + v2` Here, 'v2' gets recycled after every 21 elements

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd use `outer` rather than `map` for this:

```
sort(unique(outer(index, -10:10, "+")))
```

And, as akrun shows, you can use piping if you prefer not to nest things.

Comment: which do you think would be faster for a large df (nrow approx 10^6)?

Comment: My guess is `map` will be slowest, and `outer` will be comparable to akrun's `rep +` idea. Doesn't much matter what I think though, try it and see. Use the `microbenchmark` package. The `sort` and `unique` parts are the same in all answers, so just compare `outer` to `map` to `rep() +`. Benchmark on, say 1e4 or 1e5 elements.

Comment: If you're concerned about efficiency, it would also be worth optimizing your `sort` and `unique` options - I think `sort(unique())` will be faster than `unique(sort())`, but I could be wrong. You may also want to test `method = "quick"` vs `method = "radix"` for the `sort` - do that on a full-length vector. And depending on how the input is distributed, it might be worth running `unique()` as a very first step if there's a chance of duplicates in the input.